# Web App Architecture design with REST on Java Stack

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, web, architecture

I'm planning to build web application on top of a REST api. I have been thinking about 2 different ways to write web UI layer for controlling the views, user session management, etc.

One way : Just write everything in Javascript using Angular or similar frameworks. But, the problem I see here is, user session management and also it may not be good idea to expose everything to client. I'm thinking anybody with good knowledge of web design, can find out javascript logic and end points.

second way: Write a thin controller and user session management layer on REST in may be  Spring web mvc project / Node JS, etc, and control everything from there.  But, the problems I see here are, we have to have some end point lookup logic here, to map web ui request to REST end point. Everytime, we we add more end points, we have to maintain that catalog as well. Also, the JSONs will go through many transformations, and which may add some overhead.

can anybody suggest some architecture ideas for this ? Am I missing anything here ? Can we write secure Javascript web ui layer on REST ?

I was also thinking about having Message broker like RabbitMQ to scale it. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A very good article for your first suggestion: http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/12/securing-api-keys-in-a-client-side-javascript-app/

Comment: Thanks for the comment and sharing the article.  This is like getting OAuth token and protecting resources.  if if we have to maintain session related data, should that be in redis kind of store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first decide on how you divide responsibilities between the client and the server. What do you want the server to do, and what do you want the client to do? You already figured out that the server should hide the sensitive information, to keep the application secure. Is there anything else you need from the server? If there is a database, you probably also want to let the server handle all access to the database.

Notice that there are also alternatives such as [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), where they take care of the backend for you, and you focus on the front-end mainly. Might save you a lot of work on authentication, and data access.

You also need to think what kind of communication style they will be using? If it is Request-Response, then REST is suitable. If it is some kind of bidirectional messaging such as chat, I recommend to take a look at [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). In Meteor, you write in Javascript for front-end, back-end and mobile.

You mentioned that you're concerned with having to transform your Jsons often. If you do your server-side with NodeJS, this problem disappears. It's Javascript on the server-side.

There are many ways to implement an application. You can more specifics about what you're trying to do, and then we may recommend the frameworks that are better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It gave me some ideas to think. Thank you very much.  What I'm trying to do is,  build a common backend server infrastructure for both web and mobile.

Comment: Can you describe the application you are building? The more details you provide here, the better recommendations you're going to get on architecture and choice of frameworks.